# Does the Raspberry Pi 3 have wireless display capabilities?

Tags: wireless, pi-3

I want to buy a Raspberry Pi 3, and attach it to an external hard drive (or 2) that contains most of my media. While this is obviously simple, I want to know if the RPi 3 supports Miracast/Wireless Display. I have a Sony Bravia KDL 55W800A Television, and it is very fussy when it comes to screen mirroring, so I want to know if there is something that may break the deal when trying to create a sort-of NAS...

Comment: It's unclear if you want the Raspbery to **send** Miracast stream to the Bravia, or do you want the Raspery to **receive** Miracast stream from other device and output it via HDMI to bypass Sony screwups?

Answer (score 1):

The Pi's doesn't inherently support any wireless display standards. You need to install and configure software to do any kind of streaming. 'Normally' (*lots* of different use cases here), I would just use an HDMI cable and strap the Pi to the back of the TV.

There appears to be an inactive (last update 2014) project called [Piracast](https://github.com/codemonkeyricky/piracast) which could achieve Miracast streaming, provided you followed the instructions very precisely (specific USB dongle required, 3.5mm audio only).

A second workaround would be using a Chromecast. The latest versions of [Kodi](https://kodi.tv/) and [Yatse](http://yatse.tv/redmine/projects/yatse) will allow you to cast footage from the HD connected to the Pi via Kodi, to Yatse on an Android phone, then on to the Chromecast attached to the TV. Bit of a long way round but (so far as I've tested it) reliable.

Comment: And I thought mine was a roundabout way.... I've found my TV supports Plex as an app, and I can install RasPlex to then turn that into a streamer, but I really wanted screen mirroring....

Comment: Kodi/Yatse lets you get away with murder in that respect. You can do all kinds of deeply stupid if entertaining stream bouncing tricks between devices. Unfortunately screen mirroring is reasonably hard work if done in software, and the Pi isn't the best platform for it. Just sending streams it'll do all day long, but simultaneous capture is more difficult.