# Mirror display on a TV via wireless HDMI

Tags: hdmi

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to mirror my raspberry display to a TV using wireless HDMI. I searched and searched and I've found multitudes of blogs and questions about mirroring a phone display or a pc display, but none mirroring the Raspberry display itself.

I was wondering if anyone knew of any wireless HDMI kits out there that worked with rpi, or of any projects that leverage some. Any version Pi is acceptable. I currently have a Pi Model B but I'm looking to upgrade.

I'm only asking because I am in the planning stages of making something similar to the Super Game Pi, and I would love it if I could flip a switch, and play on a big TV via the HDMI port, but still remain in my chair, or across the room.

Thanks.

> EDIT

I've found this question [Does the Raspberry Pi 3 have wireless display capabilities?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/46674/does-the-raspberry-pi-3-have-wireless-display-capabilities) and it seems that screen mirroring is harder than it sounds. I've also looked into Picast, but its not what I needed. Along with Piracast, and its also not what I was looking for.

Would having one Pi run a VNC server and the second Pi connect to it work? I don't have any experience with VNC servers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little pricey but I would think you could just use an HDMI splitter like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00F5R9TNM). One side goes to your normal display and the other goes to a wireless HDMI transmitter like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005H3AU1Y) to your TV.

Comment: I saw those, do you know if they are compatible with the pi? I don't think I'd get one regardless, 150+ is a little pricey for something I probably wouldn't use alot.

Answer (score 0):

About the software part, i strongly recommand the tiny program `fbcp`.
Basically, it copies everything going through the HDMI output, /dev/fb0 (even disconnected) to one internal display, i.e. a touchscreen on /dev/fb1, via GPU.

https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki/Framebuffer-use

Just launch it and stop it via a tiny GPIO interface and you have your switch :)

Provided you found some wireless HDMI system, this should fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There is (supposedly) screen sharing/mirroring like you can do with phones using 'miracast' (or some other flavor of DNLA/DIAL/screen-casting) but i havent been able to get reliable screen casting working with my linux desktop (remember, the RPi runs the same (usually debian based) linux that runs on a PC, with exception to the architecture its compiled for and a few tweeks to optimize for a single board computer rather than a standard PC style system).

Other than casting, there isn't really an option to get the video from the RPi to a screen without adding some kind of hardware, and wireless HDMI transmitter/receivers can be pricey for what you're trying to do. Sure VNC might work, but I imagine there would be an issue with lag as the video is captured, compressed, transmitted, uncompressed and displayed. Where as casting tends to be a bit snappier in my experience. There is always the option of getting a long flat HDMI cable and running it under the rug across the room to the TV....